# Stop custom collection view section at needed position

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a problem with shifting section of my collection view. I am using this [CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout)

So as I see all calculation is here:

```
- (void)updateHeaderAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attributes lastCellAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)lastCellAttributes
```

My section starting at the middle of screen and then I need to know when it has origin.y = 64pt then it should stop moving to the top.

The problem is that I don't know how to get current y position of section.

Comment: isn't there a .frame property on attributes ?

Comment: @Kujey I debugged it and it's every time the same